# In-built project field names

Tags: sharepoint-addin, ms-project

I am developing a SharePoint add-in, wherein i need to get all the enterprise custom fields and the built-in project fields in a drop down. I could get all the enterprise custom fields with the below code, but not the built in Project fields:

```
function getProjectFields() {

    PC = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();
    fdls = PC.get_customFields();
    ET = PC.get_entityTypes();
    projEntity = ET.get_projectEntity();
    PC.load(fdls, 'Include(Name,Id,EntityType,FieldType)');
    PC.load(projEntity);
    PC.executeQueryAsync(ProjSuccess, ProjFailure);
}

function ProjSuccess() {

    enumfdl = fdls.getEnumerator();


    while (enumfdl.moveNext()) {

        fld = enumfdl.get_current();
        ft = fld.get_fieldType();
        fldenttype = fld.get_entityType();         

        //Check if Project type
        if (fldenttype.get_name() == projEntity.get_name()) {

            //Push to an array
            ProjectFields.push(fld.get_name());

        }

     }

    for (i = 0; i < ProjectFields.length; i++) {

       opt = document.createElement("option");
       t = document.createTextNode(ProjectFields[i]);
       opt.appendChild(t);
       selectfield.appendChild(opt);
    }


}

function ProjFailure() {

    alert('Some problem to get the Project fields!');
}
```

I would want to get the list that we find on clicking on Basic Info web Part ->Edit web Part-> Modify button, while one tries adding a web part to a page.